# Absolute and relative positioning

Tags: html, css, position

I am facing problem in CSS. I have one menu having `position: relative` and submenu having `position: absolute`.

I have used one div inside that div where there are images included, which position is relative. I have put **close button** on the top of that container, having `position: absolute`.

My problem is that my submenu is not above the images. I want my submenu to come above the images. Please help me out.

Comment: Post your html css here or fiddle it. Its very difficult to help this way!

Comment: Show your efforts by adding a snippet including your relevant markup and css demoing the problem.

Comment: Are you able to shift your menus below your images. If yes then your issue will be solved. Also you can try with placing `z-index` property for submenus higher and images to lower.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use **z-index** property order elements in the z axis.
[image]

Read more : http://html.net/tutorials/css/lesson15.php

Hope this helps